# display user choices from checkbox selections and undefined offset error

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I would display the user choices made by ticking checkboxes.  For some reason I don't understand, the array storing user choices displays as multidimensional array. The following is the code for declaring arrays:

```
//declare the array
    $languages_array = array();

    //store user input into the array
    $languages_array[] = $_POST['languages'];
```

The following is where I display information from an array:

```
print_r($languages_array);
```

This is the output I get:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => xhosa_word [1] => zulu_word [2] => sepedi_word ) )
>   Isizulu :ilizwi

Is this normal ? shouldn't this be a one dimensional array?

I also get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dictionary\results_widget.php on line 53

This is the code for displaying the above output

```
                            print_r($languages_array);
                            for($i=0;$i<$array_count;$i++)
                            {

                                if($languages_array[0][$i] == 'zulu_word') //this is line 53
                                    {
                                        echo 'Isizulu :'.$row['zulu_word'];
                                    }

                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
$languages_array = array();

//store user input into the array
$languages_array[] = $_POST['languages'];
```

You're creating a new array, and you are setting the first element of the array to $_POST['languages'].

What you probably want is this (you don't need the original array declaration):

```
//store user input into the array
$languages_array = $_POST['languages'];
```

**Update:** As for your second problem... you have a one dimensional array, but you're treating it as two dimensional here:

```
if($languages_array[0][$i] == 'zulu_word') //this is line 53
```

You probably want this:

```
if($languages_array[$i] == 'zulu_word') //this is line 53
```

Also, what is the value of $array_count? You can just use [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)():

```
$array_count = count($languages_array);
```

Comment: Updated my answer to address your second problem as well

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign

`$languages_array = $_POST['languages'];`

$_POST['languages'] is an array of fields with same name languages..

you can check if $_POST['languages'] is an array use `var_dump($_POST['languages']);`

and use  `$languages_array[0]=='anything youwanna check'`